# Dynamically append script tag inside dynamic div tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to dynamically append script tag to dynamically genarated div?

Eg:

```
<div class="test abc">

    abc

</div>
```

My code:

```
var count = 0;
$("div.test abc").append("<div id=" + "check" + count + ">"
                    +"<script type = 'text/javascript'>"
                    + "thirdpartyfunction(function(){});"
                    + "</script>"
                    + "</div>");

count++;
```

The above code just appends `<div id="check0"> </div>`

It does not append the script tag and anything thats inside it.

Comment: You're missing an ending double quote on line 4

Comment: Nope it still does not work. The missing " was a typo here. But with the missing quote also the code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a "

```
var count = 0;

$("div.test abc").append("<div id=" + "check" + count + ">"
                    +"<script type = 'text/javascript'>"
                    + "thirdpartyfunction(function(){});" ==> here                   + "</script>"
                    + "</div>");

count++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry just now saw comment by staticvoid.

Comment: Nope it still does not work. The missing " was a typo here. But with the missing quote also the code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your class selector and escape your ending script tag:

```
$("div.test.abc")
<\/script>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dd52tns/3/)

Comment: and what if I have to select using an id which is dynamic? eg: http://jsfiddle.net/02kp6nad/

Comment: Your initial question has been answered, and I would need to see more of your code to understand the new question better. It would be ideal if you create a new question and put a link here so I can take a stab at that also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007703/dynamically-appending-ids-to-dynamic-divs-in-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007703/dynamically-appending-ids-to-dynamic-divs-in-jquery  -- I've reframed & reposted the question here.. @staticvoid