# Dynamically appending id's to dynamic div's in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to dynamically append id's to the dynamically generated div's . Initially I have the first div with class "check" & then after a "show more" button is clicked , we another div with same class gets rendered. There's an ajax call here. Here's the structure:

```
<div class= "check">

</div>
```

Show more clicked: 
AJAX Call

```
<div class= "check">

</div>
```

Show more clicked:
AJAX Call

```
<div class= "check">

</div>
```

I want to dynamically append id's to the main & nested div. So I want the following result:

```
<div class= "check" id = "check_0" >
    <div id = "test0">
  <script type = 'text/javascript'>
        thirdpartyfunction(function(){});
  </script>
  </div>
</div>


<div class= "check" id = "check_1" >
    <div id = "test1">
  <script type = 'text/javascript'>
        thirdpartyfunction(function(){});
  </script>
  </div>
</div>

<div class= "check" id = "check_2" >
    <div id = "test2">
  <script type = 'text/javascript'>
        thirdpartyfunction(function(){});
  </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I tried changes id of the first div always. What the best way to go about this problem?

I tried something like this:(Pseudocode)

```
var count = 0; 
if(div with count id=0 does not exist then .. )
{
$(".check").attr("id","check_"+count);
count++;
}
```

Third party function
    
     thirdpartfunction.track(function() { test("test");})

Comment: Those dynamically generated divs are generated by some code of yours, right? If you can paste this code in your answer, we can probably give you quite a straightforward solution.

Comment: It's just a template which is generating the HTML. I have pasted the structure above though.

Comment: is that "if" really written like this in your code?

Comment: no no . It's just a pseudocode.

Comment: What I meant to ask was: are you able to change the code which does the Ajax call? The best solution requires you to add a few lines there.

Comment: what line's exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .each() of JQuery

```
$( ".check" ).each(function( i ) {
$(this).attr('id', 'check' + i);
$(this).append('<div id=\"test' +i+'\"></div>');
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.innerHTML=" alert('"+i+"');";
$(this).find('div').append(script);
});
```

Here's a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/puo906vn/4/

Comment: Would this work on a div rendered after an AJAX call?

Comment: This definitely works. Call this after each AJAX success and DOM load.

Comment: The thing is for this  $(this).find('div').attr('id', 'test' + i); , I don't have a div with id "test" inside the main div. I have to dynamically append that div inside the main div.

Comment: If you check the initial structure that I have & then the final structure that I want, the above won't really work. I'd need to have a selector to append the nested div.

Comment: so everything inside the div must be appended by you?

Comment: yes. My original structure is just <div class="check">  ... </div>  . Rest all I mentioned has to be appended by me dynamically inside that div, I believe I can add the selector in the .each() which you mentioned above.

Comment: can you show me what thirdpartyfunction(function(){}); do

Comment: That's actually private and can't put it in here unfortunately, But that has nothing to do with the appending of nested div.

Comment: see my edit for nested div, but the problem is adding the javascript, that's why I wanted to know

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean. But a script tag can be easiuly appended inside that div right?  I've updated above as to what a third party function looks like.  Thanks a ton for ur help @loli .

Comment: I updated my answer to add script tag but I put an alert, you can just change it to whatever

Comment: Ok. But instead of createElement can't we just use jquery selectorS?

Comment: yes. you could add a class to nested div like class="nested", then in jquery do $(.nested) to target them

Comment: yeah but wont that add  a new div to all the div's with that class name all the time?

Comment: eg:  $(this).append('<div class = "test test" id=\"test' +i+'\"> <script type = "text/javascript"> </script> </div>');   does not append script tag. It just appends the div. and not script inside it.

Comment: if you add class="nested" in the append, all the nested div will have that class. If you want to append script, use createElement like I did

Comment: isn't there a jquery solution for it? I thought I could append the whole script using .append() like above. All nested div's having same class name is fine. But to append script tag I cannot put it inside append() as above ?

Comment: no. What you can do is bind the function to nested divs with JQuery to an event. It all depends what your thirdpartfunction do.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var count = 0; 
if($('.check').attr('id') != 'check_'+0)
{
$(".check").attr("id","check_"+count);
count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this shorter way:

```
$(".check").each(function(key,elem){
    $(elem).attr('id', 'check_' + key)
})
```